# ErrorException Trying to get property 'slug' of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

I am a beginner to Laravel 9. I am getting error when I click edit form, and after click edit form i'm not able to submit edit but click dashboard menu in sidebar, after that given error `Trying to get property 'slug' of non-object`, i look at URL, URL changed to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/laporan-edit/dashboard`, should be there link is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard`.

My Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Laporan;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class LaporanController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $laporan = Laporan::all();
        return view('laporan', ['laporan' => $laporan]);
    }

    public function add()
    {
        return view('laporan-add');
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $validated = $request->validate([
            'nama_korban' => 'required|max:255'
        ]);

        if ($request->file('foto')) {
            $extension = $request->file('foto')->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $NamaBaru = $request->nik_korban . '-' . now()->timestamp . '.' . $extension;
            $request->file('foto')->storeAs('fotokorban', $NamaBaru);
        }

        $request['foto_korban'] = $NamaBaru;
        Laporan::create($request->all());
        return redirect('laporan')->with('status', 'Data Telah Ditambahkan !');
    }

    public function edit($slug)
    {
        $laporan = Laporan::where('slug', $slug)->first();
        return view('laporan-edit', ['laporan' => $laporan]);
    }


    public function update(Request $request, $slug)
    {

        $laporan = Laporan::where('slug', $slug)->first();
        $laporan->update($request->all());
        return redirect('laporan')->with('status', 'Data Telah Di Edit');
    }
}
```

My Model File

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Cviebrock\EloquentSluggable\Sluggable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;

class Laporan extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    use Sluggable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'petugas_pendamping', 'kronologi_kejadian', 'id_pengguna', 'nama_pelaku', 'jenis_kasus', 'foto_korban', 'tempat_kejadian', 'alamat_kejadian', 'wilayah_pendamping', 'korban', 'slug', 'nama_pelapor', 'nik_pelapor', 'alamat_pelapor', 'hubungan_pelapor', 'nik_korban', 'nama_korban', 'jk_korban', 'umur_korban', 'alamat_korban', 'nik_pelaku', 'jk_pelaku', 'umur_pelaku', 'alamat_pelaku', 'tanggal_pengaduan', 'tanggal_kejadian', 'jam_pengaduan', 'status_laporan'
    ];

    public function sluggable(): array
    {
        return [
            'slug' => [
                'source' => 'nama_pelapor'
            ]
        ];
    }
}
```

My Route

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\Events\Login;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\AuthController;
use App\Http\Controllers\UserController;
use App\Http\Controllers\RekapController;
use App\Http\Controllers\LaporanController;
use App\Http\Controllers\PetugasController;
use App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController;
use App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
})->middleware('auth');

Route::middleware('only_guest')->group(function () {
    Route::get('login', [AuthController::class, 'login'])->name('login');
    Route::post('login', [AuthController::class, 'authenticating']);
});

Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
    Route::get('logout', [AuthController::class, 'logout']);
    Route::get('dashboard', [DashboardController::class, 'index'])->middleware('only_admin');
    Route::get('petugas', [PetugasController::class, 'petugas'])->middleware('only_petugas');
    Route::get('rekaplaporan', [RekapController::class, 'index']);

    Route::get('laporan', [LaporanController::class, 'index']);
    Route::get('laporan-add', [LaporanController::class, 'add']);
    Route::post('laporan-add', [LaporanController::class, 'store']);
    Route::get('laporan-edit/{slug}', [LaporanController::class, 'edit']);
    Route::put('laporan-edit/{slug}', [LaporanController::class, 'update']);


    Route::get('user', [UserController::class, 'index']);
    Route::get('profile', [ProfileController::class, 'index']);
});
```

View edit.blade.php

```
<div class="card-body">
                        <form action="/laporan-edit/{{ $laporan->slug }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
                            @csrf
                            @method('put')
```

Im Already Try with condition like this

```
public function edit($slug)
    {
        if($laporan = Laporan::where('slug', $slug)->first()){
            return view('laporan-edit', ['laporan' => $laporan]);
        } else{
            return redirect('dashboard');
        }
        // $laporan = Laporan::where('slug', $slug)->first();
        // return view('laporan-edit', ['laporan' => $laporan]);
    }
```

it's working but, when i click sidebar another name, then it always redirects `http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard`

Comment: the link to the dashboard in your side menu should be absolute `href="/dashboard"` instead of relative `href="dashboard"`. You should also use `$laporan = Laporan::where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail();` instead of `->first()` to avoid unnecessary errors and show 404 when the link is incorrect.

Comment: thankyou for the answer. i  already add `$laporan = Laporan::where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail();` and now the error is gone. but what I want, when I'm on the edit page and I click the dashboard menu, the display should be dashboard view, not 404NotFound. i don't use href, im use controller `Route::get('dashboard', [DashboardController::class, 'index'])->middleware('only_admin');`. When im in edit page and click menu dashboard the link shown is `http://127.0.0.1:8000/laporan-edit/dashboard`, which should be `http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard`.

Comment: `Route::get(` is how you declared the route, but to help you, you need to share how the link in the side menu is made. Share the blade of the side menu.

Comment: here menu mainlayout.blade.php https://codebeautify.org/alleditor/y2206eb0a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the blade if the side menu, use absolute link `href="/dashboard"` instead of relative link `href="dashboard"`.

```html
<ul class="navbar-nav iq-main-menu" id="sidebar-menu">
    <li class="nav-item static-item">
        <a class="nav-link static-item disabled text-start" href="#" tabindex="-1">
            <span class="default-icon">Home</span>
            <span class="mini-icon" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" title="Home" data-bs-placement="right">-</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a @if(request()->route()->uri == 'dashboard') class="nav-link active" 
        @else class="nav-link" @endif
        aria-current="page" href="/dashboard">
```

or use named routes by giving an alias/name to the route and use it to generate the link

```php
Route::get('dashboard', [DashboardController::class, 'index'])->middleware('only_admin')->name('dashboard');
```

in blade

```
<a @if(request()->route()->uri == 'dashboard') class="nav-link active" 
        @else class="nav-link" @endif
        aria-current="page" href="{{route('dashboard')}}">
```

You should also use `$laporan = Laporan::where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail();` instead of `->first()` to avoid unnecessary errors and show 404 when the link is incorrect.